# Replacing the body of a proxied subrequest with the contents of a file

Tags: proxy, nginx

I'm using the [upload module](https://github.com/vkholodkov/nginx-upload-module) to write the uploaded file to disk as soon as it arrives in [nginx](http://nginx.org/). In addition, I'd like to create 2 subrequests:

1. POST to a URL containing the uploaded file
2. POST to another URL without the uploaded file

The second request is easy to do because the upload module has already stripped out the upload. My problem is with the first request: How do I get the uploaded file back into the the subrequest.

Comment: This is kind of an 'aside' but are you also using nginx to do your logging for POST requests. I can log my GET requests just fine, but I'm having trouble logging the body response from POST requests. Just thought you might have some insight. My question is posted at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939382/logging-post-data-from-request-body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [solution](https://github.com/agentzh/echo-nginx-module/commit/8d58f31a1b9883209248ee46f0cced80ad2b89f7) for my question has been committed to the [echo module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpEchoModule).

Answer (score 0):

The module you linked to has the `upload_set_form_field` directive and a few special variables (listed in that directive), which you can use to pass the file details to the backend as a POST variables. The example given appears to put the upload back in the POST data. Can you adapt your backend script to make that work?